# how to make auto select using drop down selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 drop down selection, I want to make the the second selection will auto select  when the department selected. I try to find javascript that can solve but i still cannot find it.

```
<select name="department" class="form-control" required>                                             
 <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Department -- </option>
 <option value="INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY">INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY</option>
 <option value="BUSINESS LIAISON">BUSINESS LIAISON</option>
 <option value="FINANCE & ACCOUNT">FINANCE & ACCOUNT </option>
 <option value="CEO OFFICE">CEO OFFICE</option>
 <option value="FACILITIES MANAGEMENT">FACILITIES MANAGEMENT</option>
</select>



  <select name="part" class="form-control" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- Select Part -- </option>                                         
  <option value="HICOM1">HICOM1</option>
  <option value="HICOM2">HICOM2</option>
  <option value="HICOM3">HICOM3</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this by attaching a change event handler to the first select box:

```js
var department = document.querySelector('#department');
var part = document.querySelector('#part');

department.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var value = department.value;
  switch(value) {
    
    // assign a value to `part` depending on what option we have selected:
    case 'INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY':
      part.value = 'HICOM1';
      break;
      
    case 'BUSINESS LIAISON':
      part.value = 'HICOM2';
      break;

    case 'FINANCE & ACCOUNT':
      part.value = 'HICOM3';
      break;

  
    default:
      part.value = '';
  }
})
```

```html
<select id="department">                                             
 <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Department -- </option>
 <option value="INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY">INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY</option>
 <option value="BUSINESS LIAISON">BUSINESS LIAISON</option>
 <option value="FINANCE & ACCOUNT">FINANCE & ACCOUNT </option>
 <option value="CEO OFFICE">CEO OFFICE</option>
 <option value="FACILITIES MANAGEMENT">FACILITIES MANAGEMENT</option>
</select>



<select id="part">
  <option disabled selected value> -- Select Part -- </option>                                         
  <option value="HICOM1">HICOM1</option>
  <option value="HICOM2">HICOM2</option>
  <option value="HICOM3">HICOM3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event listener to the `onchange` event of the first select.

```
<select name="department" ... onchange="myFunction()">
   ...
</select>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    alert(this.selectedIndex);
  }
</script>
```

Or, alternatively:

```
<select name="department" ...>
   ...
</select>

<script>
   document.getElementsByName("department")[0].addEventListener('change', function () {
      alert(this.selectedIndex);
   });
</script>
```

From there, you can use the `selectedIndex` to determine what you want to do with the second dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you want second dropdown auto select based on first one need reference.

```
<select name="department" class="form-control" required>                                             
 <option disabled selected value> -- Select an Department -- </option>
 <option value="INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY" rel = "item1">INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY</option>
 <option value="BUSINESS LIAISON" rel = "item2">BUSINESS LIAISON</option>
</select>

<select name="part" class="form-control" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- Select Part -- </option>                                         
  <option value="HICOM1" class ="item1">HICOM1</option>
  <option value="HICOM2" class ="item2">HICOM2</option>
</select>


********* Jquery code ********/
$('select[name=department]').on('change',function(){
        var set = $('select[name=part]').find('option.'
                  $(this).find(':selected').attr('rel'));
        /**** check set size is grater than 0 or not
        ****/
        if(set.size()<0) $('select[name=part]').hide(); return;
        /**other wise show item selected option**/
         $('select[name=part]').show();
         $('select[name=department]').
                   show().
                    first().
                     prop('selected', true);
});
```